# Two initialization Cells in one Notebook each autosaved in separate .m-file?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

Is there a way to create Notebook in which each Initialization `Cell` will be auto-saved in its own .m-file with arbitrary name?

P.S. The question is related to the *Mathematica* program developed by Wolfram Research Inc. It is not about Mathematics or math.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but just curious: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I don't think it can be done.  You could probably write an initialization cell that evaluated the code and wrote it out to a unique file, but I think that would just happen when the initialization cell evaluated, and not every time the file got saved.

Comment: @belisarius The reason is that I am developing an application intended to use slave kernels through MathLink. I need a separate initialization file for that kernels. And I feel it very comfortable to have the all my code in **one** Notebook.

Comment: And I think there are better/more reliable ways to generate packages than through the initialization-cell-saving mechanism from the old days. (Workbench, text editors, and New > Pacakge, combined with Get statements all work well, depending on the task at hand.)

Comment: @Brett In what meaning initialization-cell-saving mechanism is not reliable?

Comment: I think the auto-saving mechanism is reliable, as long as you only ever edit the notebook.  Invariably though it seems that I then wanted to edit the corresponding .m file, at which point there's a divergence in the code.  You could probably use Put or Export to generate the .m file for the slave kernels, and create a button to save the file.  It'd be a bit more manual that desired, but the button could be put in a Section cell grouping the code, or in a custom docked cell for the authoring notebook...

Comment: Alexey, would you consider Brett's suggestion in the comment above to be a solution?  Do you need help implementing it?

Comment: The Brett's method is interesting and I would appreciate a working implementation. Knowing that in really the initialization file is used only when I launch a slave kernel it would be nice to have a function that autosaves (if it is changed from the last autosaving) the current version of the cell in the .m-file before launching the kernel. The button at the same time would be also useful.

Comment: But at this moment I see another, possibly even better alternative although I am not sure that it is a reliable way: to pass on the fly the current content of the cell with initialization expressions for the slave kernels to each of them when launching it. I am doubt a little about `BoxForm` version compatibility: I work with slave kernels of *Mathematica* 5.2. But we could convert cell into `InputForm` on the fly too.

Comment: Alexey, please make sure to use the @name feature when replying to someone other than the topic starter (you, in this case).  I only saw your replies now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the following approach would satisfy you: I once wanted a way of generating compact notebooks containing only the initialisation cells found in my development notebook; the following code writes the initialization cells of the current notebook into a single new notebook and autosaves a .m file as a side-effect but it could easily be adapted to generate a separate notebook and .m file for each initialization cell.

```
In[162]:= nbToExtract = SelectedNotebook[]

In[163]:= 
extractInitializationCells[nb_] :=
 Block[{nbNew = CreateDocument[], count = 0},
  (SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell];
   While[NotebookRead[nb] =!= {}, (If[InitializationCell /. 
          Options[NotebookSelection[nb], InitializationCell],
      (count++;
       NotebookWrite[nbNew, NotebookRead[nb]]), {}]; SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell])];
   Print[ToString[count] <> " initialization cell(s) found"];
   CurrentValue[nbNew, AutoGeneratedPackage] = Automatic;
   NotebookSave[nbNew, fn];
   NotebookClose[nbNew];
   Clear[nbNew](* just in case *))]

extractInitializationCells[nbToExtract]
```

This only extracts the initialisation cells below the cell in which the function `extractInitializationCells` is called.  And I'd agree with the previous caveats about using the auto generation package mechanism.  Also, `CurrentValue` is not protected indefinitely from backwards incompatibility but it has survived several major Mathematica versions so far.

Comment: Oh, and @BrettChampion's idea of a button or similar would be needed for this approach; it wouldn't be automatic on save.  There's probably a way to modify the front end to run this on every save though.  I wouldn't know how to do that.